# Loading key from database on startup in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I have this apikey in my database. The key is used as authentication for different api server. Currently every time I make request to said server firstly I pull the key from database. I realize its unefficient way to do it so I want to hold the key in global variable that is loaded from my database on startup. How can I do it?
Code of apikey retrieving service:

```
public String getApiKeyValue() {
        Optional<ApiKey> optionalApiKey = apiKeyRepository.findById(1);
        if (!optionalApiKey.isPresent()) {
            throw new NoApiKeyInDatabase("API KEY not present in database!");
        }
        ApiKey apiKey = optionalApiKey.get();
        return apiKey.getValue();
 }
```

Comment: You can use @PostConstruct to set the API key using the repo. https://www.journaldev.com/21206/spring-postconstruct-predestroy

Comment: Add an `ApiKey` class variable to the class which defines the `getApiKeyValue()` method. if null, then lookup the value.  This would still be lazy loading though - see @Compass's comment.